# Setting boundary limits to multiple operations with random number generators

Tags: python, numpy, random-seed

I believe that my problem is really straightforward and there must be a really easy way to solve this issue, however as I am quite new with Python, I could not sort it out by my own.

I will post a made up example that I am using than the complex script which I am currently working on in case you want to test by yourself. Please, consider the following:

```
 import numpy as np 

 nData = 100
 sigma_alpha = np.array([1,1])
 alpha = [-23,0]
 data_alpha1 = np.random.randn(nData)*sigma_alpha[0]+alpha[0]
 data_alpha2 = np.random.randn(nData)*sigma_alpha[1]+alpha[1]
```

My issue is that I have to limit data_alpha1 and data_alpha2 to -25 as lower limit and 25 as upper limit. That means, all the elements on both arrays have to be in between the aforementioned values. So, the solution that I am looking for has also to involve a case where all the elements of **data_alpha1,2<25**, as the following, where multiple values will be beyond 25:

```
 nData = 100
 sigma_alpha = np.array([1,1])
 alpha = [25,0]
 data_alpha1 = np.random.randn(nData)*sigma_alpha[0]+alpha[0]
 data_alpha2 = np.random.randn(nData)*sigma_alpha[1]+alpha[1]
```

The variable alpha is in a loop, so it has a dynamic value and is constantly being update.

To sum up: what I have been trying to figure out is a way to make sure that data_alpha1 and data_alpha2 returns only values inbetween -25 and 25, and in case, any value doesn't respect the condition imposed, then it should be set to the closest boundary value which it surpasses. Like, if an element of alpha_data1 <-25, then it should be replaced by -25.

Hope that I managed to be succinct and precise. I would really appreciate your help on this one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
data_alpha1[data_alpha1 > 25] = 25
data_alpha1[data_alpha1 < -25] = -25
```